# Colored lines on startup

Tags: 13.04, updates, kernel, dell, inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 1501 running Ubuntu 13.04.  When I start up my computer there will just be a black screen with colored vertical lines. When I here the startup sound I can close my computer wait for a bit then open it and it will show the normal lines again.  Sometimes after a kernel update the lines will go away and I will see the login screen but they come back after the kernel updates again.  Are there better graphics drivers I can install.  These lines also appear when I try to launch tremulous and I can still hear sound in the background so I think it is a graphics error.  I have a `AMD Mobility Radeon Xpress 200` Graphics card and I am running the default graphics drivers installed by Ubuntu. I followed the instructions at this [Link](http://www.noobslab.com/2013/04/install-ati-amd-catalyst-drivers-in.html). But it said my device was to old and unsupported.  This is what the lines look like.
[image]

Comment: Can you post more information about your computer, such as if you are using proprietary graphics drivers and what is your graphics card maker?

Comment: It might be helpful to take a photo with a camera and post that.

Comment: I will try to post a better picture later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem goes away and comes back between kernel updates it sounds like someone is already aware of the issue and trying to fix it.

Try posting a bug report and see if it gets marked as a duplicate, then follow the original bug report to see when it's really fixed.